# Nestjs application can not run after bundled with webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, bundle, nestjs

I have a nestjs app and i use webpack to bundled this entire project to a main.js file. My webpack configure file just flowed by [this repo](https://github.com/ZenSoftware/bundled-nest) ,but when i run `npm run build:prod` to bundled main.js to dist/main.js and run  `node main.js`  it sometimes throw an error i never seen before.

like this:

```
throw new errors_1.CannotDetermineTypeError((_a = target.constructor) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.name, propertyKey);
                ^
CannotDetermineTypeError: Cannot determine a type for the "n.operation" field (union/intersection/ambiguous type was used). Make sure your property is decorated with a "@Prop({ type: TYPE_HERE })" decorator.
```

nodejs version: v12.18.4

nestjs/core version: 7.0.0

webpack-cli version: 4.2.0

my webpack config

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

const { NODE_ENV = 'none' } = process.env;

console.log(`-- Webpack <${NODE_ENV}> build --`);

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  mode: NODE_ENV,
  target: 'node',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
      checkResource(resource) {
        const lazyImports = [
          '@nestjs/microservices',
          '@nestjs/platform-express',
          'cache-manager',
          'class-validator',
          'class-transformer'
        ];
        if (!lazyImports.includes(resource)) {
          return false;
        }
        try {
          require.resolve(resource);
        } catch (err) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    })
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ configFile: './tsconfig.build.json' })]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }]
  },
  stats: {
    warningsFilter: [
      'node_modules/express/lib/view.js',
      'node_modules/@nestjs/common/utils/load-package.util.js',
      'node_modules/@nestjs/core/helpers/load-adapter.js',
      'node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js',
      'node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/ws/lib/buffer-util.js',
      'node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/ws/lib/validation.js',
      'node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js',
      'node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js',
      'node_modules/bytebuffer/dist/bytebuffer-node.js',
      'node_modules/@nestjs/core/helpers/optional-require.js',
      'node_modules/require_optional/index.js',
      'node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js',
      'node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js',
      'node_modules/ws/lib/buffer-util.js',
      'node_modules/ws/lib/validation.js',
      warning => false
    ]
  }
};
```

So can someone tell me why i had this error?

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem for properties in Mongoose object models that did not explicitly declare its types in Nest's @Prop annotation. And it must be a class, not an interface.
Like so:

```
class InnerPropExample {
    name: string
}

@Schema()
export class MongooseModelExample extends Document {
  @Prop(InnerPropExample)
  innerPropExample: InnerPropExample;
}
```

As for the reason why it happens, Nest.js doc just mentions that:

> "The schema types for these properties are automatically inferred
> thanks to TypeScript metadata (and reflection) capabilities. However,
> in more complex scenarios in which types cannot be implicitly
> reflected (for example, arrays or nested object structures), types
> must be indicated explicitly"

.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and I fix it with that prompt `@Prop({ type: TYPE_HERE })`. Like so:

```
interface MassageContent {
  txt?: string
}

@Prop({ require: true, type: Object })
  content: MassageContent;
```

it is better than changing the interface to a class